# ¿Como ocultar un botón después de una hora especifica en PHP?

Tags: php, html

Tengo 4 botones:

Quiero activar 3 botones de 9:00am a 6:00pm.
Quiero activar 1 botón de 6:00pm a 9:00am.

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
<?php
    $hora = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City'));
    $hora_actual = date_format($hora, 'G:ia');
    $hora_limite = "6:00pm";

    echo '<br><br>Hora completa: ' . $hora_actual ;

    if($hora_actual == $hora_limite){
?>
<br><br>
    <button>opcion 1</button>
    <button>opcion 2</button>
    <button>opcion 3</button>
<?php

    }else{

?>
    <br><br>
    <button>opcion 0</button>
<?php
    }  


?>
```

Comment: La hora limite tambien la deberias inicializar con la clase **Date()** para que retorne el formato de fecha y ya haces la comparación

Comment: Como seria amigo, suponiendo que son las 6:00pm? :O gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

ya que solo requieres la hora con

```
$hora_actual = date_format($hora, 'G:i A');
```

y utilizas `G` que nos devuelve la hora en formato `0 - 23` no son necesario los `minutos` o si es `am` o `pm` por lo que quedaria asi

```
$hora_actual = date_format($hora, 'G');
```

**ejemplo:**

```
<?php
    // hora
    $hora = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City'));
    // solo queremos el numero de hora
    $hora_actual = date_format($hora, 'G');
    // hora de empiezo
    $hora_inicio = 9;
    // hora de finalizacion
    $hora_final = 18;

    // imprimimos hora actual
    echo '<br><br>Hora completa: ' . date_format($hora, 'G:i A');

    // validamos que la hora_actual sea mayor o igual al empiezo
    // y validamos que la hora_actual sea menor a la final 
    if( $hora_actual >=  $hora_inicio  &&  $hora_actual < $hora_final ){
?>

<br><br>
    <button>opcion 1</button>
    <button>opcion 2</button>
    <button>opcion 3</button>
<?php

    }else{
?>
    <br><br>
    <button>opcion 0</button>
<?php
    }
```

Comment: Funciona, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

estabas cerca pero no.

```
<?php
    $hora = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
    $hora_actual = date_format($hora, 'G:ia');
    $hora_limite = "6:00pm";


    $hora = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City'));

    echo '<br><br>Hora completa: ' . $hora_actual ;

    if($hora_actual > $hora_limite){
?>
<br><br>
    <button>opcion 1</button>
    <button>opcion 2</button>
    <button>opcion 3</button>
<?php

    }else{

?>
    <br><br>
    <button>opcion 0</button>
<?php
    }  


?>
```

Tu quieres que cuando la `$hora_actual` sea mayor `>` que la `$hora_limite` salga solo un botón y cuando sea menor salgan tres. Eso no lo puedes hacer con `==` porque eso solo sucederá a las 18:00:00, después, volverán los tres botones. Por eso he cambiado el `==` por el `>`.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, lo aprecio.

Comment: hora actual jamas sera mayor ya que 6:00pm no existe es format de `G` es formato de `0 -23` por lo que sera solo 6:00am y `a` siempre es menor que `p` corregir!

Comment: Pues aquí ahora mismo son las 09:43am y me salen los tres botones. Es posible que esté mal, pero funcionar funciona.